# Creating buckets based on a target variable

Tags: r

| DSA | 3M Contribution | 6M Contribution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1.3% | 3.6% |
| BCA | 3.4% | 1.5% |
| CDE | 0.8% | 0.1% |
| DCA | 0.1% | 2% |
| EDA | 2% | 0.7% |

I have a dataset with 3 variables with column name DSA having upto 180 levels. Column 3M and 6M contributions add up to 100% respectively. I want a random grouping within DSA where the sum of 3M contribution accounts to 10% in each group. It doesn't matter the count of DSA in the group as long as it accounts to 10%, for eg. 20 DSA can account to 10% in one group and 15 DSA can account to 10% in another group. Key here is randomness in the distribution in different groups. Same solution i'll replicate for 6M contribution. Would request a solution with minimal hard coding.

Forgot to add one thing, I need a possible solution which breaks my dataset into 10 bins/groups of +- 10% contribution in each group **(each group being unique from one another)**. It doesn't have to be exactly 10% in each group, tolerance range of +- 0.5% is acceptable.

Comment: This sounds like a rephrasing of the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which is NP hard, meaning it unfortunately doesn’t have an efficient solution. The most efficient solution is via [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving), but in the worst case it needs to try all possible combinations.

Comment: Since it is an urgent requirement I could do with a solution which is less efficient too.

Comment: Actually this looks more like the [0–1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) than bin packing. My previous comment already links to the correct section for an optimal, relatively straightforward algorithm to solve it (still NP hard, though). Unfortunately the algorithm assumes integer weights. Using non-integer weights makes it rather more complex.

Comment: How close does it need to be to 10%? Is there an acceptable tolerance?

Comment: As you said it doesn't have to be exactly 10%, anything close to 10% would work fine as well. But how do you make lets say 10 groups of approximately 10% in each group with you solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how close to 10% you need the values to add to. Here's a solution that should give acceptable results unless you need the values to add up to *exactly* 10, in which case you may be very limited in the sets that you can "randomly" choose, as per Konrad Rudolph's comments.

We can replicate your data structure like this:

```r
set.seed(3)

df <- data.frame(DSA = apply(replicate(3, sample(LETTERS, 180, TRUE)), 1, 
                             paste, collapse = ""),
                 x = rexp(180),
                 y = rexp(180))

df$x <- 100 * df$x/sum(df$x)
df$y <- 100 * df$y/sum(df$y)

names(df) <- c("DSA", "3M Contribution", "6M Contribution")
```

So now we have:

```r
head(df)
#>   DSA 3M Contribution 6M Contribution
#> 1 EFS       0.6825126       1.2142943
#> 2 ZDL       0.0751734       0.1383280
#> 3 LWK       1.6487536       0.6453974
#> 4 GBY       2.1218616       0.2870302
#> 5 DDU       0.3414601       2.6318194
#> 6 ZHT       0.2341914       0.4497800
```

There are 180 rows, each with a unique 3 letter identifier for `DSA` and each of the `3M Contribtion` and `6M contribution` columns add to 100:

```r
length(unique(df$DSA))
#> [1] 180

sum(df$`3M Contribution`)
#> [1] 100

sum(df$`6M Contribution`)
#> [1] 100
```

Now that we have the data, we can select a random ordering of the data frame by doing:

```r
sample_df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

All this does is put the data frame rows in an arbitrary order. However, we can now get only the first `n` rows that allow `3M contribution` to (approximately) add to 10 like this:

```r
sample_df <- sample_df[cumsum(sample_df$`3M Contribution`) < 10,]

sample_df
#>     DSA 3M Contribution 6M Contribution
#> 59  QQQ      0.85167563      0.02718667
#> 43  WJY      0.35287431      1.40795918
#> 165 ISF      0.47397401      0.32810467
#> 114 GVV      0.35121926      0.56594478
#> 42  EHT      1.44584224      0.33704927
#> 71  DJX      0.84489716      0.16338381
#> 2   ZDL      0.07517340      0.13832804
#> 110 PZM      0.98701927      0.07642120
#> 11  JME      0.22959383      2.31503532
#> 153 BER      0.09994387      0.61655857
#> 81  UXU      0.22244869      0.31506248
#> 166 QYV      0.86343465      1.62441563
#> 171 SPH      2.43818827      0.84201677
#> 131 MAB      0.64740835      1.06533067
```

And we can see that we have a completely random selection of 14 DSAs that add up to (almost) 10:

```r
sum(sample_df$`3M Contribution`)
#> [1] 9.883693
```

And if we run it again, we get a completely different set

```r
sample_df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
sample_df <- sample_df[cumsum(sample_df$`3M Contribution`) < 10,]

sample_df
#>     DSA 3M Contribution 6M Contribution
#> 165 ISF      0.47397401      0.32810467
#> 2   ZDL      0.07517340      0.13832804
#> 129 XAN      0.68953299      0.23862892
#> 37  OFV      0.32093896      0.54626344
#> 56  ZSU      0.85837341      0.15694326
#> 42  EHT      1.44584224      0.33704927
#> 115 YEB      0.05722397      0.81590015
#> 89  SQV      0.34496853      0.32799710
#> 67  DBT      0.82052602      0.47833734
#> 124 ZOI      0.01553935      0.49215515
#> 125 GLS      1.87641137      0.70018877
#> 91  AOW      0.55159848      0.09659654
#> 38  JPH      0.05702578      0.02310634
#> 62  RGO      0.57398460      0.20540972
#> 139 LOA      0.34511367      0.38109741
#> 154 NWH      1.04575037      1.08159278
#> 114 GVV      0.35121926      0.56594478
#> 47  DIL      0.07265622      0.18332102
```

On this occasion, we have a set of 18 randomly chosen DSAs that again add up to almost 10:

```r
sum(sample_df$`3M Contribution`)
#> [1] 9.975853
```

And if you want to get 10 such samples, you can get them all in a list, like so:

```r
all_samples <- lapply(1:10, function(x) {
  sample_df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),];
  sample_df[cumsum(sample_df$`3M Contribution`) < 10,]
})
```

Now we have a list of 10 samples called `all_samples`, and we can get each just by using subscripts. For example, the fifth such sample would be obtained like this:

```r
all_samples[[5]]
#>     DSA 3M Contribution 6M Contribution
#> 147 YQZ      0.85928604      0.07089867
#> 84  WUD      0.15243070      0.09202777
#> 103 WSQ      0.27323608      1.79443012
#> 166 QYV      0.86343465      1.62441563
#> 1   EFS      0.68251264      1.21429430
#> 52  YTJ      0.61530262      0.47584261
#> 98  DVY      0.61661083      0.46831908
#> 3   LWK      1.64875363      0.64539744
#> 8   KDV      0.05386368      0.31977784
#> 41  CQE      0.85948052      0.14494440
#> 99  YSU      0.69153090      0.96764012
#> 72  LZZ      0.77170284      0.29414941
#> 170 BRA      0.15377281      0.54707772
#> 95  OAF      0.68996185      0.73363205
#> 69  ICC      0.71197929      0.16501976
#> 82  BMR      0.12875373      0.07509324
#> 169 HWR      0.01473804      0.71425244
#> 124 ZOI      0.01553935      0.49215515
#> 157 SGN      0.06565888      0.29731670
```

And we can see that the sum is still close to 10%:

```r
sum(all_samples[[5]]$`3M Contribution`)
[1] 9.868549
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but just can I ask for one addition where I can get 10 such datasets of approximately close to 10% and each set has to be unique, that's the key thing

Comment: @rak953 sure, that's straightforward just using a loop or `lapply` - see my update for an example

Comment: Life saver. Thanks a lot bud.